# R packages won't install on conda R environment

Tags: linux, package-management, bioinformatics, r, rstudio

I am trying to install an R package to an R environment created through conda on an HPC Server where I am doing some bioinformatics. I tried to run the usual R command (which works and install the requested package in my local RStudio installation):

```
install.packages("http://hartleys.github.io/QoRTs/QoRTs_LATEST.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source");
```

However, when I try to run this same command in my conda R environment I keep getting the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"http://hartleys.github.io/QoRTs/QoRTs_LATEST.tar.gzhttp://hartleys.github.io/QoRTs/QoRTs_LATEST.tar.gz"'
```

Any ideas as to why the normal syntax isn't being accepted in the conda R installation, what syntax do I use in this instance to overcome this issue and install packages through conda on a unix server?

Comment: Based on the error message, it sounds like you are typing the `install.packages()` command at a bash shell prompt, instead of inside an `R` session

Comment: But I created and activate a conda R environment so surely it should work?

Comment: I used "#CONDA CREATE NEW R ENVIRONMENT
conda create -n r_env r-essentials r-base
conda activate r_env" to create and activate the environment. How would I create an R session inside a linux terminal?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about conda to offer a solution. I suspect that adding arbitrary packages *within* the environment may be non-trivial - see for example the discussion [Using R and conda](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-r-and-conda/10960)

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned by @steeldriver in the comments, you should open an R session before trying to use `install.packages()`. After activating your conda environment with `conda activate r_env` just type `R` in your command prompt. Afterward, your installation should work. Workflow:

1. open your terminal and connect to the HPC server.
2. activate your conda environment using `conda activate r_env`
3. open R session using `R`
4. install the R package using `install.packages("http://hartleys.github.io/QoRTs/QoRTs_LATEST.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`
5. continue as you would in your local RStudio